# Mostrar Horario dependiendo de un intervalo de tiempo

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo 2 variables PHP, una contiene una hora inicial y la otra una hora final. Por ej:

```
$var1 = '08:00';
$var2 = '16:00';
```

Luego tengo otra variable, que es un intervalo de tiempo, es decir, que contiene la cantidad de minutos a mostrar por cada hora. Por ej:

```
$intervarlo = '15'; //15 minutos
```

Ahora, lo que debo hacer, es mostrar una lista de las horas comprendidas entre $var1 y $var2 considerando el intervalo de minutos ($intervalo).
Para este caso de ejemplo, los resultados a conseguir, serian:

```
|HORARIO|
| 08:00 |
| 08:15 |
| 08:30 |
| 08:45 |
.........
| 15:30 |
| 15:45 |
| 16:00 |
```

Cabe considerar, que $var1, $var2 y $intervalo, son datos que vienen desde mysql. Esto debe imprimirse en una table html.
Alguna idea de como hacerlo o alguna informacion al respecto para poder orientarme?. saludos y gracias a todos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacer esto con la ayuda de **[`DatePeriod`](http://php.net/manual/es/class.dateperiod.php)**, es una clase que nos permite:

> La iteración sobre un conjunto de fechas y horas, repitiéndose a
>   intervalos regulares durante un período dado.

Seguiremos la siguiente lógica:

- LLevaremos todo al terreno de los objetos, para poder tirar de sus grandes ventajas, por tanto a partir de `$var1` y `$var2` crearemos dos objetos `DateTime`
- Notarás que hay una pequeña astucia de modificar en 15 minutos la fecha de fin, esto es porque `DatePeriod` no incluye la fecha de fin. Con ese pequeño *trick* obtendremos también la hora `16:00`
- Se crea un rango de fechas entre la fecha de inicio y la fecha de fin y luego se imprime en un bucle. Si en vez de imprimirlas las necesitas para usarlas en otra parte, las puedes meter en un array.
- Aquí no he usado tu variable `$intervarlo` por comodidad mía, pero puedes usarla para concatenar los valores que se usarán como modificación y como intervalo.

El código sería este:

```
$var1 = '08:00';
$var2 = '16:00';
$intervarlo = '15';

$fechaInicio = new DateTime($var1);
$fechaFin = new DateTime($var2);
$fechaFin = $fechaFin->modify( '+15 minutes' ); 

$rangoFechas = new DatePeriod($fechaInicio, new DateInterval('PT15M'), $fechaFin);

foreach($rangoFechas as $fecha){
    echo $fecha->format("H:i") . PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Salida:**

```
08:00
08:15
08:30
08:45
09:00
09:15
09:30
09:45
10:00
10:15
10:30
10:45
11:00
11:15
11:30
11:45
12:00
12:15
12:30
12:45
13:00
13:15
13:30
13:45
14:00
14:15
14:30
14:45
15:00
15:15
15:30
15:45
16:00
```

Espero te sea de utilidad.

---

#### Fiddle

Puedes ver aquí una **<kbd>[DEMOSTRACIÓN](https://rextester.com/ZJRRI38870)</kbd>** en línea y hacer pruebas sobre el código. En la demo he incluido la posibilidad de guardar las horas en un array.

Comment: muchisimas, gracias. era justo lo que necesitaba. agradecido de su tiempo y buena disposicion. Saludos y gracias nuevamente.

Comment: Estimado, si bien el codigo anterior funciona correctamente, una consulta aparte. Usando el mismo codigo y teniendo en una tabla un registro inicio y termino (ej: inicio: 09:00 y termino 10:00), como podria hacerse para que al realizar la consulta mysql, apareza el rango desde las 09 a 10 bloqueado o no disponible? Agradezco cualquier ayuda que pueda brindarme. Saludos.

Comment: @maha1982 Me alegro de que la respuesta te haya ayudado. Ahora bien, tu nueva duda tendría que ser planteada en otra pregunta. Stackoverflow funciona por pregunta (una duda, una pregunta). La idea es no mezclar, porque una misma pregunta/respuesta (s) pueden servir a otras personas con un problema similar.

Comment: Perfecto, lo planteare como nueva pregunta. Muchas gracias por su ayuda. Saludos.