# detectar colisiones en los horarios

Tags: php

Tengo un pequeño proyecto donde guardo el día y la hora en que un trabajador comienza un trabajo.

Un trabajador puede tener muchos trabajos durante el día.

Lo que quiero es si los trabajadores están fuera de horario. Ejemplo si un trabajador comienza a las `10:00:00` y finaliza un trabajo a las `12:00:00`. No podría haber trabajado de `11:00:00` a `12:30:00`.

**Estoy validando esta información ya en mi backend y frontend. Pero hay información mal ingresada posteriormente y quiero guardar esta data mal ingresada en un array para luego mostrarlo hora errónea donde se traslapa el horario en mi frontend**

```
<?php
$data = [
    array(
        'trabajador_id' => 1,
        'hh_inicio' => '12:30:00',
        'hh_termino' => '13:30:00'
    ),
    array(
        'trabajador_id' => 1,
        'hh_inicio' => '11:30:00',
        'hh_termino' => '13:00:00' /*Error porque trabajo a las 12:30:00 anteriormente*/
    ),
    array(
        'trabajador_id' => 2,
        'hh_inicio' => '10:30:00',
        'hh_termino' => '13:30:00'
    ),
    array(
        'trabajador_id' => 2,
        'hh_inicio' => '13:30:00',
        'hh_termino' => '14:30:00'
    )
];
$array_error = array();
foreach ($data as $x) {
    $trabajador_id= $x['trabajador_id'];
    $hh_start  = $x['hh_inicio'];
    $hh_end    = $x['hh_end'];
    echo "\n>" . $trabajador_id. " hh_inicio" . $hh_inicio. " hh_termino" . $hh_termino;
    // if ($hh_inicio=<$hh_termino) {
    //     $array_error[] = 
    //     array(
    //         'trabajador_id' => 2,
    //         'hh_inicio' => '13:30:00',
    //         'hh_termino' => '14:30:00'
    //     );
    // }
}
  echo "\n";
if(!empty($array_error)){
    echo "Error fuera de horario";
} else {
    echo "Correcto";
}
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que para esto trabajes con objetos `DateTime` y que uses Intervalos para verificar. Hacer esto a mano es infernal y propenso a muuuchos errores.

Comment: Mira si [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/476430/29967) puede darte una idea, o también [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/235539/29967). En ellas se usa `DateTime`, con `DateInterval` y `DatePeriod`. Con esa combinación podrás resolver muy sencillamente situaciones complejas.